# table caption tag for docx

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx

in 
http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCaption.php

it is written that

```
<w:tblCaption w:val="caption text"/>
```

is the tag for table caption , but when I add it to the xml, I get error and also the caption is not shown.
When I add the caption directly from the Word it is added as :

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00346450" w:rsidRDefault="00346450" w:rsidP="00346450">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Caption"/>
        <w:keepNext/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>caption text</w:t>
      </w:r>
 </w:p>
```

I use Word 2010, can someone explain this? maybe w:tblCaption  isn't used anymore and it was not updated in officeopenxml.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the page you link to: the tblCaption tag is a child element of tblPr (table properties).

What this page does *not* tell you is that this is not a "caption" in the sense of the term Word users understand it. It's actually the "Alt-text" for a web-page, in case the Word document is saved as a web page. So it's never going to be visible in the Word document. You can see the option in the UI by selecting the table, going to the "Properties" dialog and choosing the "Alt Text" tab.

A "real" caption is the Word Open XML you show in your second code snippet. What marks it as a caption is the *style* applied to it. It can be positioned anywhere in the document, although Word's built-in tool to insert a caption will offer to place it above or below the object it's for.